# Youtube API - Use URN id

Tags: youtube-api, urn

i am using the Youtube API to retrieve a playlist content of videos

In of the list of entries, i get all my videos and their unique ID is what youtube call "URN id".

But I can't find a way to play these video using the URN id. It works fine with the real v=xxXXxXx ID but URn id seems to be different and i can't find the v=xxXXxXx anywhere in the feed

Can anyone help please?
Aperage

Answer (score 1):

The playlist feeds contain the `videoid` which you can use to get the `v=xxxxxxx` url.

Sample [playlist feed](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/AE7D3F0082186088?v=2) from the API, the id's of the videos can be found in `<yt:videoid>`, for example `<yt:videoid>pPF2H95gEBU</yt:videoid>`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but while parsing the URL with simplexml_load_file, i don't see any nodes yt:videoid ? I can the real IDs in the source when I manually call the link to the youtube feed but the don't appear in the object tree build by simplexml_load_file

Comment: @Andre Philippe Make sure you are using version 2 of the API, by appending ?v=2 at the end of the url like on http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/AE7D3F0082186088?v=2

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I had tried both version

Finally found the solution...

After using the simple xml, I added these to access the real video  ID

$i=0;
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
    $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    
    // get video player URL
    $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
     
    $xmlEntries[++$i]['id'] = $this->getYoutubeId($attrs['url']); 
    $xmlEntries[$i]['title']= strval($entry->title); 
}

Comment: @Andre Philippe the `videoid` **is** there... if you can't find it, you are looking in the wrong place.